# Azure Machine Learning extension install on my remote computer through my vs code client

Tags: vscode-remote, azure-machine-learning-service

I'm using Visual Studio Code on my Mac.
I added the Remote development plugin to this environment.
I am able to connect to the Azure machine learning compute remotely via SSH.
However, after connecting to the remote compute, the remote compute asks me to install the Azure Machine Learning plugin, and after I approve the installation, the remote compute seems to be trying to install it, but the installation is still in progress.
Is there any way to install it?